# Can i use multiple Vue Composable functions in one file? how do I structure it?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

Can i use multiple vue composables in one file?
example:

```
<script>
export function arrayToInt(arr) {
...
}

export function arrayToUint(arr) {
...
}
</script>
```

then somewhere else:

```
import {arrayToInt, arrayToUint} from "./useBytesHelper"
```

because im getting a vue router parsing error right at the beggining when loading my app. and i might be doing this wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the file is JavaScript module (useBytesHelper.js) and not Vue SFC (useBytesHelper.vue), it's incorrect to use `<script>` tag there.

The rest is correct, it should be used as listed:

```
import {arrayToInt, arrayToUint} from "./useBytesHelper"
```

Comment: is there a more vue-ish way to do that?

Comment: Vue is JS framework. This is the way it's done in JS. .vue files are for components. For other exports, use .js